# Prove that $\mathbb E[\sup_{s\in [0,t]}M_s^2]\leq 4\mathbb E M_t^2$.

Tags: probability, martingales

Let $(M_t)$ a continuous martingale. Prove that $$\mathbb E\left[\sup_{s\in [0,t]}M_s^2\right]\leq 4\mathbb E[ M_t^2].$$

I already proved that $$\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\right\}\leq \frac{\mathbb E|M_t|}{y},$$
and I know that $$\mathbb E Y^2=\int_0^\infty 2y\mathbb P\{Y>y\}d y,$$
when $Y\geq 0$ a.s. I tried to use this last formula for $Y=|M_t|$ but it's not conclusif. How can I conclude ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a finer version of $$\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\right\}\leq \frac{\mathbb E|M_t|}{y}$$

which is 
 $$\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\right\}\leq \frac{\mathbb E(|M_t|1_{\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\}})}{y}$$

By integrating both sides with respect to $y$ , we have

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{y\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\right\}dy}\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathbb E(|M_t|1_{\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\}})}dy$$

Using Fubini theorem on both sides, we have
 $$\mathbb E\left(\frac{\left(\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right)^2}{2}\right) \leq E\left(|M_t|\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right) $$

or

$$\mathbb E\left({\left(\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right)^2}\right)^2 \leq 4 E\left(|M_t|\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right)^2 $$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and the fact that $\left(\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right)^2=\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|^2$ a.s., we conclude that 
$$E\left(|M_t|\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right) \leq \sqrt{E\left(M_t^2\right)E\left(\left(\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right)^2\right)} $$

and finally,

$$\mathbb E\left[\sup_{s\in [0,t]}M_s^2\right]\leq 4\mathbb E[ M_t^2]$$

Comment: can you please provide more details to why $E\left(|M_t|\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathbb E(|M_t|1_{\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\}})}dy$ ? I'm finding it hard to see the link with Fubini's theorem

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathbb E(|M_t|1_{\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\}})}dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left( \int_{\omega \in \Omega}{  |M_t|1_{\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\}}}d \mathbb{P(\omega)}\right)}dy=\int_{\omega \in \Omega}{ |M_t| \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}{ 1_{\{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|\geq y\}}dy}\right)}d \mathbb{P(\omega)}=\int_{\omega \in \Omega}{ |M_t| \left( \int_{0}^{\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|M_s|}{ dy}\right)}d \mathbb{P(\omega)}$$